# Is there a name for the extent of an object in a 4th and higher spatial dimensions? (width, height, depth, …)

Tags: geometry, terminology

If *width* is the extent in the first dimension, *height* in the second and *depth* in the third, is there a name for the extent of an object in the fourth spatial dimension?

And what about a five, sixth and higher dimensions?

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange Mathematics, Mathis. I would encourage you to view https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask, in particular the advice 'Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?'
It seems on this occasion you did post a duplicate question, but please do not be disheartened! I'm sure the community will welcome your further contributions to the site.

Comment: Well, I guess that answers it. But it's certainly disappointing that there doesn't seem to be a better term than "spissitude".

Comment: Yes, it seems just as archaic as referring to the x and y axes as the abscissa and ordinate

Comment: There might be if you invent one. (Also the linked answer only cites one person and doesn't give the impression that the term caught on)

Comment: You've not explicitly used *breadth* or *length* BTW. And everyday speech does talk about time  having length. It might get confusing using some of the words together, though.